# Display image created using GD library in different PHP file

Tags: php, ajax, gd

I have index.php where I ask user to select two images to combine.. The selection is done using check boxes.
User then clicks on the button on which I pass the selected image paths to MergeImages.php , the merge image.php combines the two icons with some other processing and create one image, which I need to display on the index.php just below the list of images.

Here is my code for that
Index.php

```
var Images;
Images = listOfImages.join("|");
$.ajax({
url: 'MergeImages.php',
type: 'POST',
data: {listOfImages : Images},
success: function(data) {
 alert("success");
 $("#output_image").attr("src","MergeImages.php" );
 },
 error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
 console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
 }
 });
 }
```

MergeImages.php

```
imagecopy($dest, $src, 0,0,0,0,$swidth,$sheight); 

header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($dest);
```

The image is not displayed, what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You make POST request to `MergeImages.php`, but on success you do not use the returned data. Instead, you set image `src` to `MergeImages.php`, which calls it, but without PST arguments (it's an ordinary GET request without any arguments).

You need to use `data` in your success handler. This is where your response from POST request to `MergeImages.php` is. To do that, see the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802312/display-png-image-as-response-to-jquery-ajax-request).

If possible, replacing GET with POST in `MergeImages.php` might make things easier for you. In that case, you wouldn't need AJAX, but you'd just set the image's `src` attribute to `"MergeImages.php?icon1=bla&icon2=bla"`.

Comment: I am now trying with GET like this, $('#output_images').html('<img src="MergeImages.php?listOfIcons=Icons" />');  This doesnt display the image...

Comment: If `MergeImages.php` uses $_POST, it doesn't get `listOfIcons`. Test it first by invoking it itself from the browser, i.e., by calling directly `http://localhost/wherever/your/script/is/MergeImages.php?listOfIcons=Icons`. When this gives you an image, then your code should work.

Comment: If I do $('#output_images').html('<img src="MergeIcons.php?icon1=Images/xyz.png&icon2=Images/abc.png" />'); then it returns the created image and its displayed. ( hard coded path ) But these image paths are in an array , so when I do $('#output_images').html('<img src="MergeIcons.php?icon1=listOfImages[0]&icon2=ListOfImages[1]" />'); that doesnt work, it does not display the image. My PHP code is changed to GET  $firstIcon = $_GET['icon1']; $secondIcon = $_GET['icon2'];

Comment: JavaScript doesn't work with strings the way PHP does, so `ListOfImages[0]` and `ListOfImages[1]` will not get substituted with their actual values. You can simply put `$('#output_images').html('<img src="MergeIcons.php?icon1=' + listOfImages[0] + '&icon2=' + ListOfImages[1] + '" />');` or, maybe better (if the number of images is not constant), create a string: `var s = ""; for (var i = 0; i < ListOfImages.length; i++) s += (s ? "&" : "") + "icon" + (i+1) + "=" + ListOfImages[i];` and then you can use `$('#output_images').html('<img src="MergeIcons.php?' + s + '" />');`.

Answer (score 0):

I think returning the image is not a good idea, unless every time a request is made you generate a new image.

To improve cacheability, you shoud return a response redirected to the url of the image on the server.