# How to Pass Multi Images into jQuery Ajax Responde

Tags: php, ajax

Can you please take a look at this demo and let me know how I can send the 4 generated images to client side using jquery ajax?

As you see I have a

```
<?php
$a = "A";
$b = "B";
$c = "C";
$n = "8";

$ima = imagecreate(100, 30);
$bg = imagecolorallocate($ima, 255, 255, 255);
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($ima, 0, 0, 255);
imagestring($ima, 5, 0, 0, '$a, $textcolor);
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($ima);
imagedestroy($ima);

$imb = imagecreate(100, 30);
$bg = imagecolorallocate($imb, 255, 255, 255);
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($imb, 0, 0, 255);
imagestring($imb, 5, 0, 0, '$a, $textcolor);
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($imb);
imagedestroy($imb);

$imc = imagecreate(100, 30);
$bg = imagecolorallocate($imc, 255, 255, 255);
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($ima, 0, 0, 255);
imagestring($imc, 5, 0, 0, '$a, $textcolor);
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($imc);
imagedestroy($imc);

$imn = imagecreate(100, 30);
$bg = imagecolorallocate($imn, 255, 255, 255);
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($ima, 0, 0, 255);
imagestring($imn, 5, 0, 0, '$a, $textcolor);
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($imn);
imagedestroy($imn);
?>
```

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802312/display-png-image-as-response-to-jquery-ajax-request

Comment: Thanks Surgeon, but my question is different! I am asking to send 4 images to client side? what is the best to do this?

Comment: It is actually the same, you can just concat the binary, and split it after you receive.

Comment: Is there any way to wrap the images in HTML format and send to  client side?

Comment: Please read what I have included in my first comment. It already shows you how you can wrap it.