# Making an API request for an image using Axios, receiving unknown characters as response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, request, axios

I'm attempting to make an API call to my Node/Express backend where I send it the location of a stored avatar image along with a jwt, and it sends me the image (a jpeg) in response. The request goes out and returns successfully but rather than receiving the image, I get this string of text/unknown characters:

```html
                                                                                                                                    ����JFIFHH��~ExifMM*�i�P��d�e�2017:08:31 12:49:45ASCIIScreenshot�� �http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/<?xpacket begin="" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?> <x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="XMP Core 5.4.0"> <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"> <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:photoshop="http://ns.adobe.com/photoshop/1.0/" photoshop:DateCreated="2017-08-31T12:49:45"/> </rdf:RDF> </x:xmpmeta>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 <?xpacket end="w"?>��8Photoshop 3.08BIM8BIM%��ُ�� ���B~��4ICC_PROFILE$applmntrRGB XYZ �

9acspAPPLAPPL���-appl��g�F�K�Dn�u�
desc�ecprtd#wtpt�rXYZ�gXYZ�bXYZ�rTRC� chad�,bTRC� gTRC� descDisplay P3textCopyright Apple Inc., 2015XYZ �Q�XYZ ��=�����XYZ J��7
�XYZ (8ȹparaff�
P� �sf32B����&�������������n��e"�� 
���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� 
%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������� 
���w!1AQaq"2�B���� #3R�br�
$4�%�&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������C








��C ��G��?��T/)q�������#�oa4��p���ԒA��_\G�Lۿ�_���Q��:~�.��>����k�+��]�;6��E�n��
�Km��b��M��k&_�(~����������綕k�ɦ��=R�I��O��_�����˪����"��Qm1xr��Q��O]9?��5��|=��� ҏ�����ƻ���2y����z/�(~�� ���G�j������?��?��5����2[��s�{
�ME�Ϳ�*_F�� wg���ћ�]������������٣���|%���7XH�2ox{o1K�U����������h3������i?�:2,���������
G�k���燀�#U��Ǳ�<�]��"?�0�ا��Ɓ��Y�,��?�_�����䚻�tM�@i���k,�]��W�G|� ����
�F2,������祦���7��_�úNbc�@�p�{>!�{�y�(N��~¿�����B��Cر�||9�`���'�t\|��W��Ƒ�9w?A�
9����"�?�N��
7�?[8����S�KS�?��v��H͹��K�8�����)�ӥ�C`�����5m�?��?��5���ۓ�'�tpy���T�������C��ӱ�`����̗�
�B�N������dhZ!�5�w��Ȁ�G�#ؘ�$��{?�[JU��r�G�j���Q�-�������������
bK�h�|�Z>�c�9��V~���sL-�������ը��66NB?�?�_������$b��/ú.L&��{
�$�g���A��@6Q���ҋ���Yw}� ��ƿ=�A���������0���W��G����]ϻ��
����/��Ƙ?�zI86Q���:�:o�y���D~�����P�NP��).�����E�mc>�����h�������<�wB'�Y>�������U������>������6x�O����'�7���>i�}�[�z9�7���x
���{��˻>�O��E-���?�F����чKDo����z l�g���{D�Qo�T�����.������@�������f����x����$�D���o
���?                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  <?xpacket end="w"?>��8Photoshop 3.08BIM8BIM%��ُ�� ���B~��4ICC_PROFILE$applmntrRGB XYZ �

9acspAPPLAPPL���-appl��g�F�K�Dn�u�
desc�ecprtd#wtpt�rXYZ�gXYZ�bXYZ�rTRC� chad�,bTRC� gTRC� descDisplay P3textCopyright Apple Inc., 2015XYZ �Q�XYZ ��=�����XYZ J��7
�XYZ (8ȹparaff�
P� �sf32B����&�������������n��e"�� 
���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� 
%&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������� 
���w!1AQaq"2�B���� #3R�br�
$4�%�&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������C
��T/)q�������#�oa4��p���ԒA��_\G�Lۿ�_���Q��:~�.��>����k�+��]�;6��E�n��
�Km��b��M��k&_�(~����������綕k�ɦ��=R�I��O��_�����˪����"��Qm1xr��Q��O]9?��5��|=��� ҏ�����ƻ���2y����z/�(~�� ���G�j������?��?��5����2[��s�{
�ME�Ϳ�*_F�� wg���ћ�]������������٣���|%���7XH�2ox{o1K�U����������h3������i?�:2,���������
G�k���燀�#U��Ǳ�<�]��"?�0�ا��Ɓ��Y�,��?�_�����䚻�tM�@i���k,�]��W�G|� ����
�F2,������祦���7��_�úNbc�@�p�{>!�{�y�(N��~¿�����B��Cر�||9�`���'�t\|��W��Ƒ�9w?A�
9����"�?�N��
7�?[8����S�KS�?��v��H͹��K�8�����)�ӥ�C`�����5m�?��?��5���ۓ�'�tpy���T�������C��ӱ�`����̗�
�B�N������dhZ!�5�w��Ȁ�G�#ؘ�$��{?�[JU��r�G�j���Q�-�������������
bK�h�|�Z>�c�9��V~���sL-�������ը��66NB?�?�_������$b��/ú.L&��{
�$�g���A��@6Q���ҋ���Yw}� ��ƿ=�A���������0���W��G����]ϻ��
����/��Ƙ?�zI86Q���:�:o�y���D~�����P�NP��).�����E�mc>�����h�������<�wB'�Y>�������U������>������6x�O����'�7���>i�}�[�z9�7���x
���{��˻>�O��E-���?�F����чKDo����z l�g���{D�Qo�T�����.������@�������f����x����$�D���o
���?
```

I've also tried using Postman to make the request, and am able to successfully receive the image.

```html
//getting token from sessions storage, decoding stored info, storing //url in variable

let token = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
let decoded = jwt_decode(token);
let avatarUrl = decoded.avatar

let config = {
  headers: {'Authorization': "Bearer " + token}
};
let bodyParameters = {
  key: "value"
}

//sending avatarURL along with jwt token. image response expected
axios({
  url: 'API ENDPOINT',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Authorization': "Bearer " + token,
  },
  data: {avatar: avatarUrl}
}).then((response) => {
  console.log(response.data)
}).catch((error) => {
  alert(error)

})
```

Comment: Your _string of text/unknown characters_ __is__ your image. What did you expect when you `console.log` it?

Comment: You're getting the image file back, in binary. Printing it to the console will make the browser interpret it as text, resulting in gibberish. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19681224/5734311) for a way to turn `response.data` into a blob and subsequently use it as image.