# Is there a way to get around cors not enable server?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, angularjs, ajax

Is there a way to download an image into the browser. And then use that data to draw an image using canvas? I saw a lot of post about XHR request and stuff. But I am new. So I don't have much knowledge about javascript, ajax, or jQuery.

I saw a post here [How to be able to convert image to base64 and avoid same-origin Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29644474/how-to-be-able-to-convert-image-to-base64-and-avoid-same-origin-policy) but it doesn't seem to work for me and especially I want the code to run on smart phones (android/iOS).

Comment: and you dont have access to the server side code?

Comment: Sure, just download the image on your own server.

Comment: Is there a way to download image on to the browser (client-side) itself? Or download image as temporary file. And then use file as source?

Comment: No, you can get cross-origin images, but you can't use them in a canvas, as it violates the same-origin policy.

Comment: So is there an equivalent to canvas that won't violate same-origin policy?

Comment: Nope, there's the serverside, which can get the images for you and generate a link on the same origin.

Comment: Can I use 'http://crossorigin.me/' to get around this?

Comment: Sure, if you want to use an external proxy, that should work as well.

Comment: Somehow I still got the same error :-/