# FileStream response shows � instead latin characters

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, filestream, asciiencoding

kindly read the whole question,
I have a application in C# ASP.NET MVC. Which does a Ajax call on a function which returns a PDF file using `FileStream` with response **STREAM A**. And due to that it do not renders the file properly. The file is just empty page with no text in it when opened. 
 `FilestreamResult` in ASP.NET MVC returns a response **STREAM A** while returning a PDF file

**STREAM A**

```
%PDF-1.3
%����
7 0 obj
<<
/Type /ExtGState
/ca 1
>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/Parent 1 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 595.28 841.89]
/Contents 3 0 R
/Resources 4 0 R
>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<<
/ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]
/Font <<
/F1 6 0 R
>>
/ExtGState <<
/Gs1 7 0 R
>>
>>
endobj
8 0 obj
<<
/Producer (��pdfmake)
/Creator (��pdfmake)
/CreationDate (D:20140526100505Z)
>>
endobj
10 0 obj
<<
/Type /FontDescriptor
/FontName /AAAAAA+Roboto-Regular
/FontFile2 9 0 R
/FontBBox [-479 -271 1170 1058]
/Flags 32
/StemV 0
/ItalicAngle 0
/Ascent 1048
/Descent -271
/CapHeight 1048
/XHeight 0
>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<<
/Type /Font
/BaseFont /AAAAAA+Roboto-Regular
/Subtype /TrueType
/FontDescriptor 10 0 R
/FirstChar 33
/LastChar 53
/Widths [586 568 252 523 249 550 568 874 568 252 529 641 659 583 343 346 568 757 345 878 513]
/Encoding /MacRomanEncoding
/ToUnicode 11 0 R
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Pages 1 0 R
>>
endobj
1 0 obj
<<
/Type /Pages
/Count 1
/Kids [5 0 R]
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<<
/Length 218
/Filter /FlateDecode
>>
stream
x���=N�0�~N1����I�bl
�H6A����שhH,n����Fطs�]�����'
����4��O<��
x^�/Ϋ��J}ӟO��s�ũ�
����C(��땞*���щ"��Kٙ���XD��sŶd�f�a�Ŋ&��b8H9Ⴙ��@|Ѵ+,�Ȥ��}dxu%���Ѷ�ME7S����AXUm�j����xWϿ
endstream
endobj
9 0 obj
<<
/Length 3042
/Filter /FlateDecode
/Length1 4920
>>
stream
x��X
pSU�?����i�&M�R�4��H۴T��� (P*�|I��MhmS�`��f][l�������CR�.*���#�u����CѝYg����s�{)Iq�d������9�w�9�� ���ohq��6��<r��6\I��)^�=��ipd�OoH��,����y_a�a�/ ^���r$�rģ��hqt��
� ь���i��Jn�2ĕ��W������m��sg��W8�� �Ij����g
�cc�ka�Jwf�p������E�mQ;w�8��@���d�����ǵ~2�_@,z��Rl���9�p.�,�_��e�=̬8    �*��vS�FQ�B�b��!�1��ڛvlR��fͲ��\Q�5CTᅝT�y���w���;��A�H���s�u��#ۖ����)��#N����,�EC4� f���3z��/�D~�~~�M���v���/%�!�_��en���,xX����"�����SZ�>y���l�}�uӐ�W�7�\T8�t��ၴDR;����>j8M��2��A`��1NQfVffq�Je�"dLI5��SDkFfI�=5�^8���?2��y����woX�ؙ.�8��HO����^^��ݷu�y\\�y}y�=i9{���d��v�`<7"�����#���D'GXK���Hp��d�_k<�=�E�c�
�Lֲq�0w��VȌ�i�����^,Ӵfeʙ�|��*)��s�5��$��H���>�m��8A��o��B�m::�=�
�dV�_ٷ�ئ:�c����7����6�i]���wqu$���5�]2[9�1�j�u==�.�3W�[3��K�u���;�;��Y�bϭ�;�y����\�h�2_�E��/�H�c|� �D��5$F��`RXX����lC��~�鉮O$Q|��y��pۋ�[[\��?�y�:_:�^V�t�o����.��ٝ�7�C��]����b�<����������52;��_d'�
������8`��!�b�d��!�H�˅��K�Q��   :���p�>�DM��i��w�!?^
_��]�w������ǯ,�]�Xr�y6/7{�$����6���!�H=�k�
rME���\%F{�@<�XY����G�i�����@�E�T��(?�����E�|�F�J�ZbE��,XC����5b8����|�۷˹�dY��/6��Q��CF��}ο�=��/��]�m�R��CS|l��0�=�#\;4X!�e.҄DV��0.@8�l���IJ��$�����:͂��3d!]A�{��p�bxiz���/��.�ߟz����]]8
�/�ї8�e���d>��x�'��&�   h�O�v��z�,������Ar��Nօ_
u���/~(��υ/��>�7v����D#�)��C����]�f�F�V ��jl�g�)]M63�y�����n��&�;]eC�촜�_U��1�����Ɇ'�Z��c�*-�F����CMA�������C�X#��2�d�����"�F��@`a���$�d��~B�B����Jˠ=��MiA�!��5����"��
��@�oT����L7
���F�ZĜ�1�$)S�z&�ꨕ���
���C�ۍV\��g�[����̙yE��)�5ٝ�G�
��7zC��s���ɦ'��'{����P��z
+���*��ܺ��i��6@�}�̯�%�.���m1�ō�eo����V~���(�����
�G��<��33����QGRvW]��7;�V��K/���*�_zS�k.��%vW#l���"AJ�lG�$#H�6H�e   h5uR�A��b-K���UN�O�C��
��Ο��%I�%mJz0����I"K���`7Hgb��T*�J���8�܁/�Ŵ�O�O��5W���?|�yl�v�U��R��Ӵ�8�s��-���Is1_֎�W�ln��a�I��R)���=��o��b�H;>yGeR�3ad�t�ȑ?=��p��d��U�.p�{w��V����X��wt�\��
�=l��.������Z���t
V��`Y���Z;�N��A����y�[�=�~-_;�\��`=���s�K��#�T��,b%*[�Q�H�G�)Bx���L��7|��*ZF��
�MB���Aȅ�_L����j@oqw�N7��$� �%�U]9&��Y��5��E�_CD\�E+��<�    ��ٶ`�a2��p79�
�!� N�$/�SB��J��3$���S:�>K�s�sN�0O�2~���F8,&����z��~7�P�y4J�
����0���́���B��� }姤g��Dȥ���*�M������>�������S�Nz׊��J�T؋G�x"k't��n����3����h(�%�V���7V�JX���o3p���:��A+�'����~���V�8���H��V���EN��ȣ�)z��"�`
�P��E��=�(r�"��QE.@IV�"�}S���T�QAiW�q �Wyh���<4$���!��U�Z0���2ɿy�ѩ�<��{�c?������+�dH������3;>������u76�̋<��f��0��7�L;��8����j@Yt���M��"�y5�Q!NM���{|X�#�x����ո���E�oނ�;�+�+��6+���y{���hEh$F��F��j��3�\�v���\�W��_PT0�Q�cֹP_;�c�ͨ3�|I{s�    �˥O�l2W1�8�n7;�>���jqx7�=���Mpɍ��R\}hցqvA�Di�<��Jlt�d5�2Eq��%�Ni�Z*���v���jF�\^_��*p�����Q7c<e�wʑ�Rw�����4oiu��f_��\��h�e$� aa^>֫
�PW;���q^3:^�\����:�OF����db��F~���Vj�utt�9$�<�F[��E�m��+W.�e^�t���R�O��7-޴����")�z;J�bW���*��,�}�d}BF���c����.����d�TN-:ng��|T0��,n��C�n���jD�}
endstream
endobj
11 0 obj
<<
/Length 317
/Filter /FlateDecode
>>
stream
x�]��n� ��<�,�E��؉dY�ҍ���nÐ"�a��ۇ�D�t�>�|88;o������#�t�u��0��:Q�������,� �������Nd�����W�L�Bs��`�v_��gƫ�?8������&m�G�w9#dl�:�۸���W��y��(��{$�h\�T���������:��R�pLF}� �����P�    K��HX1�k¶"<�9aÂ��eD�#�&<����g��x T�ah3 cChx�2a�����m9o�������5e�8o3q�S#tsϦ�5�T2_/�K�Z��?�/�\����u
endstream
endobj
xref
0 12
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000936 00000 n 
0000000887 00000 n 
0000000993 00000 n 
0000000169 00000 n 
0000000059 00000 n 
0000000612 00000 n 
0000000015 00000 n 
0000000286 00000 n 
0000001283 00000 n 
0000000398 00000 n 
0000004412 00000 n 
trailer
<<
/Size 11
/Root 2 0 R
/Info 8 0 R
>>
startxref
4802
%%EOF
```

It gives `�` for latin letters like ÿ ö Ú and so on.

I want that file to stream like

**STREAM B**

```
%PDF-1.3
%ÿÿÿÿ
7 0 obj
<<
/Type /ExtGState
/ca 1
>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/Parent 1 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 595.28 841.89]
/Contents 3 0 R
/Resources 4 0 R
>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<<
/ProcSet [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]
/Font <<
/F1 6 0 R
>>
/ExtGState <<
/Gs1 7 0 R
>>
>>
endobj
8 0 obj
<<
/Producer (þÿpdfmake)
/Creator (þÿpdfmake)
/CreationDate (D:20140527071607Z)
>>
endobj
10 0 obj
<<
/Type /FontDescriptor
/FontName /AAAAAA+Roboto-Regular
/FontFile2 9 0 R
/FontBBox [-479 -271 1170 1058]
/Flags 32
/StemV 0
/ItalicAngle 0
/Ascent 1048
/Descent -271
/CapHeight 1048
/XHeight 0
>>
endobj
6 0 obj
<<
/Type /Font
/BaseFont /AAAAAA+Roboto-Regular
/Subtype /TrueType
/FontDescriptor 10 0 R
/FirstChar 33
/LastChar 53
/Widths [586 568 252 523 249 550 568 874 568 252 529 641 659 583 343 346 568 757 345 878 513]
/Encoding /MacRomanEncoding
/ToUnicode 11 0 R
>>
endobj
2 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Pages 1 0 R
>>
endobj
1 0 obj
<<
/Type /Pages
/Count 1
/Kids [5 0 R]
>>
endobj
3 0 obj
<<
/Length 218
/Filter /FlateDecode
>>
stream
x­Ò=NÄ0à~N1Àñ¼ÿIbl
òH6A¬Äù×©hH,nÆúôüFØ·s·]ÙÄåÂÓ'
óÏÇ4¿O<­´
x^§/Î«ðûJ}ÓOÌsÊÅ©×
ÏÂ®ÝC(áë*½üÑ"ÂØKÙûXDêsYÌd³f¼aìÅ&§b8H9á¹á@|Ñ´+,­È¤ãö}dxu%ÇÃõÑ¶­ME7S½óóAXUmÝjÀøËÞxWÏ¿
endstream
endobj
9 0 obj
<<
/Length 3042
/Filter /FlateDecode
/Length1 4920
>>
stream
xX
pSUö?÷¾¤iÚ&MÓR4ÒýHÛ´TÊ ¥ (P*´|I·¦MhmSÒ`ÛÑf][lª¨CR».*®­#ÒuÔÅÿºCÑYgÝÔsß{)IqÖdÞËûûÞ9çwî9çÞ ù°îohq´6 ä<r»6\Iû)^ =ÚìipdÌOoHð¡,¯©Å×y_aÜaÄ/ ^ÓÔär$ÄrÄ£ïhqt¶Ñ
® ÑØÜæi÷ÑJnâ2Ä­WÃ«ô÷ðmø¸sgËÞW8³ð ÀIj¦g
Åccøka·Jwfàp·àØÀ×øEÛmQ;w­8@Ôê×d¯±»íÇµ~2_@,z«ÞRlá»Ã9Áp.ß,¯_ûe½=Ì¬8   *¿ÁvSFQ­B bªÐ!Ð1ÀéÚvlRfÍ²¦Ñ\Q¦5CTáTßy°áwíÞ;³AîHåêás¡uôð#ÛÍ½)ô£#N¼âÝ,EC4â fêü3zî¶/×D~Ü~~Mé­Åvââ/%Æ!_ãØen¯,xXÖÊâ"Ó¤¡æSZ>yöàÓl­}íuÓéWë7é\T8ãtþÄá´DR; Åâ>j8MçÏ2´A`ÚÍ1NQfVffqJe"dLI5¥¦SDkFfI=5Õ^8ã¾?2øÖyè¨woX÷Ø.8ûHO½õî^^Ý·uÇy\\´y}yÙ=i9{·îød·èvÔ`<7"ç³²Á#³D'GXK©ÒHp´âd_k<©=«EcØ
¤LÖ²qÌ0w³VÈ¦iÉÌÌÆÔ^,Ó´feÊ|§Î*)¹sÓ5ñ¤$°áHàÆß>÷m¬ë8AÅËoÑêBßm::å=ë
dVº_Ù·ÿØ¦:cøÀ©7ý¡ÿ6íi]äï¼wqu$¹ò5À]2[9ñ1Ùjêu==¼.3W¦[3ÌKu°éØ;ÁÍ¾íYbÏ­ª;óy¨êé\±hô2_ñEô /ÖHäc|Ñ ÐD5$F`RXXÐè¨lC§Ó~Áé®O$Q|°¹yýpÛï[[\¿?½yã:_:ê^Vãt®oþú¡.ºëÙ»7©C÷Ò]û¸§bô<²£Ð¾Üô52;Éí_d'õ
õÄþ¨£8`Ã!bêd±Æ!ñHÖË¢ÒKµQÌÏ  :÷÷¦p>ùDMç´i«wï!?^
_¨¨]þwåð»áëÇ¯,«]«Xræy6/7{Ì$Àîú6ÊÚë!¬H=©kè
rME®÷Ë\%F{Ò@<¨XYÄÛãGâiíÀ³ñØ@ÐEñTé¦(?¶ÅÅE|FJ¢ZbE,XC´ê«ð5b8ñ÷Ð|Û·Ë¹·dYéÛ/6ìÖQòÃCFû}Î¿=üß/]¸möRîCS|l¥£0=þ#\;4X!óe.ÒDV0.@8ÆløØIJ$¶òÆÞ:Í3d!]A{Ðpøbxizª·¯/¼.üßzÿÊÓý]]8
/Ñ8ôeìd>âËx¯'º&Ê    hOùv½Åz£,ãá£ÖArÜNÖ_
uýú/~(øÃÏ/½>7vÍðÐÇD#Õ)ó£Còã÷]áf©FV ­jl÷gÙ)]M63¸yð¤ú¬n§&Þ;]eCýì´_U©1±§êØÉ'¿ZØcâ*-ÔFÞÂëCMAî½¥ûèÐCX#÷ú2ædÌýÔ"ÐF@`aÔêü$²dö~BÙB¥¬ÎJË =®ÊMiA¿!ïÑ5©Ó¸Ý"Öü
¾ô@õoT¼²ÿ»L7
óÀ÷FÍZÄ1$)S½z&éê¨Óù
Ãþ¶CÑÛV\´g[Ëõ¤ïÌyEúº)©5ÙÝG
óÂ7zC¥sÕâ£É¦'÷Ó'{Àü£Põz
+õ¦*ÀÈÜºi±Ò6@ª}ÎÌ¯´%.m1¤ÅÛeoõÒúV~¨®¯(ø©øé
§G<±¦33³«¦ûQGRvW]ùÓ7;VôK/«*_zSk.ð%vW#lÿµõ"AJÌlGÈ$#H6HÃe h5uRÝA¢b-KªªUNOµCõ
¥¼ÎÒ%I÷%mJz0éñ¤ýI"K½Ä`7Hgbå²T*ÎJìä8õÜ/ÒÅ´OO÷ÿ5WÌþ¸?|úylûvêUõöRÿÓ´ï8ùs¨-îÄIs1_Ö×WÌlnÙáaäIô¾R)¤è=­Îoö§bÞH;>yGeRÉ3adtáÈ?=±pæ¤dûÔUÕ.p{w½òV¼æ¼ØX¿«wt\ÿâ
¬=lã.¹³ñZÏt
VÙð`YåõZ;ÙNúîAç×Åy´[µ=Ú~-_;°\½`=³µsØKÍÒ#Tô,b%*[¦QHG)BxúöðLÁü7|ÿõ*ZF«È
ßMB¯ÞAÈ½_LÅÜ×Âj@oqwëN7ÒÎ$ %ÿU]9&±YÕá5ÛÝEÇ_CD\ÐE+ë¸<Ú    úøÙ¶`ða2ýÛp79ô
ù! Ní$/SBÊûJ´Â3$¿ÝäS:>Ks·sNî0Où2~ÿ­°F8,&«Ðýzï~7ôPúy4J²
°ÉÄ0ôÍÁÂBäÀ }å§¤gëÅDÈ¥ïÁ*MÁàº>ô¾¦æÍSÿNz×þ¤JTØGÊx"k't¿ônÆÞÇð3¶h(%°Váý°7VÁJXÁo3p´Á:¸ßA+¥'¦¹ã~¤ãVø8üH¡VÓENñíÈ£È)zù"ç`
ìPäÁEÎã=(r¦Â"ÐëQE.@IVä"Ç}S¬TîQAiWäq WyhÉë<4$¨Èã!UäZ0¯¹2É¿yäÑ©<ÖÓ{Æc?¾¤È¡+òdHäî¸ËÓê3;>¹ÁÓÖåu76ùÌ<Æf¹0¿ 7ÿL;¾ö8Á¿¼j@YtÜÐMÒè"y5Q!NM®ðÔ{|X#õxøÀ³ÂÕ¸¥ÙáEoÞ·;À+Û+ï6+·¢y{ÚÒhEh$FÊFí±jþ×3«\Þv·§Õ\W_PT0Q¶cÖ¹P_;cÔÍ¨3|I{sÆ    ÚË¥O¶l2W1©8àn7;Ì>¯Ãéjqx7=¸æMpÉ¦ÌR\}hÖqvADiÊ<øçJltód5Ñ2Eq§%öNi¦Z*¼îvÛÑjFÏ\^_»§*pÚØôµ£Q7c<e·wÊûRw«µÝå4oiuº¼f_Ë\ÞæhÀe$Ç    aa^>Ö«
ºPW;¨q^3:^\å:¼OF±Ïä dbôF~Ï×Vj³uttä9$ò<ÞF[³ìE»méÝ+W.Ìe^°tô¡RüOÇÒ7-Þ´½")Úz;JbW©À¶*±ã,Ä}d}BF±êÁc¦ñ£.éÿ®ÁdµTN-:ng¿§|T0ú,n½ºCªn¥ßýjDú}
endstream
endobj
11 0 obj
<<
/Length 317
/Filter /FlateDecode
>>
stream
x]Ínë ÷<Å,ÓEäßØdYªÒ··ºnÃ"Õa²ðÛD©t¶>à|88;o³²°¨#ëtÀu¹0áÅ:Q ­¿Õ,½ ó¸­çÁºNdÿÒòÃ»W½LøBsÆ`Ýv_çgÆ«÷?8£¾&m÷Gúw9#dlÝ:­Û¸íëWñ¹y({$µh\½T¤» èò¼ïé:ýßRùpLF}Ë º²èúP÷  KÂæHX1kÂ¶"<9aÃ°eDÂ#£&<±µgáÄx TüahÂ3 cChx2açm9oÛÞó­â¼5e¨8o3qS#tsÏ¦Õ5T2_/·K½ZÏ?À/\üÜÿu
endstream
endobj
xref
0 12
0000000000 65535 f 
0000000936 00000 n 
0000000887 00000 n 
0000000993 00000 n 
0000000169 00000 n 
0000000059 00000 n 
0000000612 00000 n 
0000000015 00000 n 
0000000286 00000 n 
0000001283 00000 n 
0000000398 00000 n 
0000004412 00000 n 
trailer
<<
/Size 11
/Root 2 0 R
/Info 8 0 R
>>
startxref
4802
%%EOF
```

**C# CODE**

```
    public FileStreamResult GetFileStream()
    {
        string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "uploads/";
        string fileName = "template.pdf";
        return new FileStreamResult(new System.IO.FileStream(path + fileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open), "application/pdf");
    }
```

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
function ajaxFileStream() {
    //jQuery.support.cors = true;
    var url = "/Home/GetFileStream";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET", //POST
        url: url,
        crossDomain: true,
        //data: {},
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response); // here i get STREAM A 
            //do some operation on response
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
}
```

Is there any change in 
**Server Side:** while streaming the file in some charactertype like utf-8 or something orther. 
**Client Side:** some function code in javascript to convert from **STREAM A** to **STREAM B**

Any suggestions are welcome, Thanks in advance.:)

Comment: This sounds like the client side misinterpreting the response as text rather than binary (As you're using FileStreamResult server side the actual response should be binary). Id consider checking out this answer which may allude to a solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/10646659/1370442 . Might be handy to post your javascript code and the C# serverside method too!

Comment: OK, I think i was on the right lines checkout this post by Mozilla on how to modify your javascript code in order to receive binary data ;o) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data

Comment: was checking out the same thing. hope it may help. Anyways thanx for the reply. It means a lot :)

Comment: No worries, once you have the code working you should add your new code as your own answer - may well help other out in the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, just need to set responseType to `arraybuffer` for the ajax request. Since, the jQuery does not supports that dataType, have to use traditional Javascript Ajax

For more Info see [Sending and Receiving Binary Data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data)

```
function ajaxFileStream() {
    var url = "/Home/GetFileStream";
    var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oReq.open("GET", url, true);
    oReq.responseType = "arraybuffer";

    oReq.onload = function (oEvent) {
        console.log(oReq.response);
        var blob = new Blob([oReq.response], { type: "application/pdf" });
        var win = window.open('', '_blank');
        var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        var dataUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        win.location = dataUrl;
    };
    oReq.send();
}
```

Thanks, [bUKaneer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1370442/bukaneer) that linked helped a lot.

Comment: Nice one, glad you got it working in the end, happy to help ;o)