# Entire JavaScript array prints OK, but not one cell

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have to process a JS `Uint8ClampedArray`. When I print the full array with `document.write(data)` the result is fine, but when I access to the first item `document.write(data[0])` the result is some undefined and wrong numbers.

The array is created like this:

```
var myArray = new ArrayBuffer(imgData.data.length);
var data = new Uint8ClampedArray(myArray);
data=httpRequest.responseText;
```

The information comes from a C cgi program which prints binary data this way:

```
 for(int i = 0; i<len; i++)
    printf("%u", input[i]);
```

Comment: you do realize that setting `data=httpRequest.responseText` overwrites 'data'? Data now isn't a Uint8ClampedArray anymore, but just a string containing the information from your request.

Comment: `data` is not an Array, so you cannot do `data[0]`. (Technically a string *is* sort of an array but certainly a string isn't what you are expecting.)

Comment: Hint: see this answer for the correct way to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645847/ajax-binary-response#answer-10646659